# Dropdownlist never show under the parents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdownlist in a bar, but no matter what I did, the dropdownlist will never appear below the parent. Here is my css code:

```css
 ul{
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
   margin-left:auto;
   width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F9282F;}


    li a{
   display:inline-block;
   color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   font-size:15px;
   font-weight:bold;}

    li a:hover{
      background-color: #111;}

    .dropdown {
   position:relative;
      display: inline-block;}

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #800000;
      min-width: 160px;}

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #111;}
```

```html
    <li class="dropdown" ><a class="dropbtn">BlaBla</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">link 1</a>
      <a href="">link 2</a>
     </div></li>
```

Hope someone will help me get out of this problem. THANKS!

Comment: Look again on the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41800053/483779) you accepted, it stops working if you put <ul> tag back.

Comment: Also you never be able to select the dropdown menu with that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add color blank to your class (.li a) and add margin-top:50px to your class(.dropdown-content) and its start working.

```css
 ul{
   list-style:none;
   padding:0;
   margin-left:auto;
   width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F9282F;}


    li a{
   display:inline-block;
   color: #000;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
   float:left;
   font-size:15px;
   font-weight:bold;}

    li a:hover{
      background-color: #111;}

    .dropdown {
   position:relative;
      display: inline-block;}

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #800000;
      min-width: 160px;
      margin-top:50px;}

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #111;}
```

```html
    <li class="dropdown" ><a class="dropbtn">BlaBla</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="">link 1</a>
      <a href="">link 2</a>
     </div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `top: 100%;` to `.dropdown-content`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `li a`. You're trying to float the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Parent shouldn't take float:left
so this `style="float: none;"` will solve the problem

```
<a class="dropbtn" style="float: none;">BlaBla</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using floats in cases of dropdown lists can generally be a bad idea. You can achieve most of the work by using display-inline block, UL and LI elements only as structural (f.e. define width), and elements inside to present them selves like A.

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:100%;
}


li a{
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #F9282F;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}

ul.root {
    height: 50px;
}

ul.root li {
    position: relative;
}

ul.root ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="root">
    <li class="dropdown" ><a class="dropbtn">BlaBla</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>Something else</div>
```

Edit: I updated the code a bit so you wouldn't have a problem with any elements underneath. You can use z-index if you have issues with overlaping order.